# SSO Enabled CMS Web 8.5 throws an error

Tags: topology-manager, sso

We have enabled SSO on one of the CMS servers, everything works fine but when we try to map a Publication to URL in the Publication properties under Publishing tab, the moment we navigate to that tab we get an error in the notification bar:

```
/WebUI/Models/TTM/Services/TopologyItems.svc/GetWebApplicationsForEnvironments failed to execute. STATUS (404):
```

I have tried so many different config changes, but with no luck, and I did not notice any special error happening at the server, EventViewer

Answer (score 1):

Your error message indicates a 404 error, meaning the TTM services can't be found in IIS.

Can you verify that Topology Manager is correctly installed in your environment ?

Something else you might need to check is if in your server settings, Http Activation for WCF is configured correctly (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32206669/1947899).

Comment: Thanks Harald for your answer, I was working with SDL support, and they pointed out a misconfiguration we had, and that was SSL endpoints were not enabled for the service, when I did that the issue was resolved